# Unable to put table next to each other

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have read through other posts but it seems that using `display:inline-block` and `float:left` doesn't fix my problem. Here's what I have:

```css
.leftTable {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: auto;
  border: solid 1px black;
  width: 20%;
}
.rightTable {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: auto;
  border: solid 1px black;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<table class="leftTable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <form action="TestMartController" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="dairy">
        <input type="image" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/categories/dairy.jpg">
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <form action="TestMartController" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="meat">
        <input type="image" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/categories/meats.jpg">
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <form action="TestMartController" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="bakery">
        <input type="image" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/categories/bakery.jpg">
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <form action="TestMartController" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="fruitveg">
        <input type="image" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/categories/fruit &amp; veg.jpg">
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="rightTable">
  <tr>
    <th>img</th>
    <th>product name</th>
    <th>price</th>
    <th>button</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The result I got was

```
[leftTable]
[IMG]
[IMG]
[IMG]
[IMG]
[rightTable]
[IMG] [Product Name] [Price] [Button]
```

I want the desired result of

```
[leftTable]               [rightTable]
[IMG]          [IMG] [Product Name] [Price] [Button]                                         
[IMG]
[IMG]
[IMG]
```

I can't seems to spot the mistake, does anyone have suggestion on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach might be to use `display: inline-table` on your two tables, since you want them to behave like inline elements.

Floats could also work but it depends on other factors in your layout.

```css
.leftTable {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  display: inline-table;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.rightTable {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  display: inline-table;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table class="leftTable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <form action="TestMartController" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="dairy">
        <input type="image" src="http://placehold.it/101x50">
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <form action="TestMartController" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="meat">
        <input type="image" src="http://placehold.it/102x50">
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <form action="TestMartController" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="bakery">
        <input type="image" src="http://placehold.it/103x50">
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <form action="TestMartController" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="fruitveg">
        <input type="image" src="http://placehold.it/104x50">
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="rightTable">
  <tr>
    <th>img</th>
    <th>product name</th>
    <th>price</th>
    <th>button</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the tables inside a container and position the containers next to each other using the `float` attribute in CSS.

HTML

```
<div class="table1_con">
<table></table>
</div>

<div class="table2_con">
<table></table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
Body, html {width:100%;}
.table1_con {width:20%; 
             position:absolute; 
             float:left; 

.table2_con {
     width:80%; 
     position:absolute; 
     float:left;
}
.table1_con .leftTable{
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: auto;
    border: solid 1px black;
    width: 100%;
} 
.table2_con .rightTable{
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: auto;
    border: solid 1px black;
    width: 100%;
}
```